# why does a parameter passed into a stored procedure cause MySQL error 1267?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, mysql-5.1

Both of these stored procedures compile in my MySQL 5.1.73 server:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_admins()
    BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Accounts
                INNER JOIN LINK_Account_Status ON Accounts.account_id=LINK_Account_Status.account_id
                    AND LINK_Account_Status.active_ind=1
            WHERE Accounts.active_ind=1
                AND Accounts.`type`='admin';
    END $$
delimiter ;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_admins2(
    IN  p_type  varchar(50)
)
    BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Accounts
                INNER JOIN LINK_Account_Status ON Accounts.account_id=LINK_Account_Status.account_id
                    AND LINK_Account_Status.active_ind=1
            WHERE Accounts.active_ind=1
                AND Accounts.`type`=p_type;
    END $$
delimiter ;
```

Executing `CALL get_admins();` returns the results I expect.

Executing `CALL get_admins2('admin');` errors:

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

The observant responder will notice there is no functional difference between the two resulting queries. I have double-checked that `Accounts.type` is, indeed, a `varchar(50)` (even if it is unfortunately-named).

What in the [Sam Hill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Hill_%28euphemism%29) is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `COLLATE` in your `WHERE` condition to solve this like below

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_admins2(
    IN  p_type  varchar(50)
)
    BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Accounts
                INNER JOIN LINK_Account_Status ON
Accounts.account_id=LINK_Account_Status.account_id
                    AND LINK_Account_Status.active_ind=1
            WHERE Accounts.active_ind=1
                AND Accounts.`type`=p_type COLLATE utf8_general_ci; /* <-- Here */
    END $$
delimiter ;
```

You can as well add the COLLATION in parameter declaration itself (["As of [MySQL] 5.5.3, COLLATE can be used..."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)) like:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_admins2(
    IN  p_type  varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci <-- Here

.....<rest of the code here>.....
```

**EDIT:**

After doing some search I found that, this issue may occur if your columns have different collation even though tables have same collation. See the below MySQL Forum post

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,265345,265579

Comment: "Parameter types and function return types can be declared to use any valid data type, except that the COLLATE attribute cannot be used." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @JeromyFrench, Yes; I missed that you are using 5.1.*. Then you can use it in `WHERE` condition but in MySQL 5.6 or higher you can use `collate` in parameter declaration as well; as you have already edited. Yup thanks for that.